# How can we iterate through a column vertically downwards using PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, iteration

For instance, in a dataframe where col1 is the name of a column and it has values 1,2,3 and so for every row, how do I iterate through the 10,20,30.. values alone?

Comment: can you explain the example a bit more. you have values as 1, 2, 3 and want to iterate 10, 20, 30? where is this 10, 20, 30? here are some links to help you ask on SO -- [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Well... Bluntly said, in Spark you just don't iterate. You don't deal with rows in Spark. You just learn a new way of thinking and only deal with columns.

E.g., your example:

```py
df = spark.range(101).toDF("col1")
df.show()
# +----+
# |col1|
# +----+
# |   0|
# |   1|
# |   2|
# |   3|
# |   4|
# |   5|
# |   6|
# |   7|
# |   8|
# |   9|
# |  10|
# |  11|
# | ...|
```

If you want to get only rows where col1 = 10,........ 20,........ 30,........ 40......... you must see a sequence there. You think about it and create a rule to smart-filter your dataframe:

```py
df = df.filter('col1 % 10 = 0')
df.show()
# +----+
# |col1|
# +----+
# |   0|
# |  10|
# |  20|
# |  30|
# |  40|
# |  50|
# |  60|
# |  70|
# |  80|
# |  90|
# | 100|
# +----+
```

Row order is never deterministic in Spark. Every action changes row order. Sorting is available, but it's costy and impractical, as next operation will ruin the order. When you sort, you pull everything into one machine (only when data is on one node you may, at least temporarily, preserve the order, because normally data is split across many machines and none of them is "first" or "second"). In distributed computing, data as much as possible should stay distributed.

That said, iterating rarely may be needed. There's `df.collect()` which (same as sorting) collects all rows into one list in one machine (the driver - the weakest machine). This operation is to be avoided, because it distorts the nature of distributed computing. But in rare cases it is used. Iterating over rows is an exception. Almost any data operation is possible without iterating. You just search the web, think and learn new ways of doing things.

Comment: That was insightful, thanks a lot! df.collect() method works